# Multiple MySQL Table JOINS needs to concat the results of 1 table into a single column field

Tags: mysql, sql, database, magento, join

I have this SQL query below which takes all my order records from a MySQL DB table and gets the `order_id`, `order_number`, and `item_status` column for each record in the `nam_order_items` DB table.

It then JOINS the `order_id` on the above table with the `parent_id` field on the `sales_flat_order_address` table in order to get the shipping address data for all the orders in my `nam_order_items` DB table.

So far up to this point it all works as I need it to....

```
SELECT sfo.order_id, sfo.order_number, sfo.item_status, shipping.city 
FROM nam_order_items AS sfo
JOIN sales_flat_order_address AS shipping ON shipping.parent_id = sfo.order_id
AND shipping.address_type =  'shipping'
```

Now to add on to this SQL I also need to JOIN and query another 3rd DB table to get all the related `comments` for an order record.

The order comments are stored in this DB table `sales_flat_order_status_history` under the `comment` column.

So I add another JOIN to the above SQL so that is looks like below...

```
SELECT sfo.order_id, sfo.order_number, sfo.item_status, shipping.city, comments.comment
FROM nam_order_items AS sfo
JOIN sales_flat_order_address AS shipping ON shipping.parent_id = sfo.order_id
AND shipping.address_type =  'shipping'
JOIN sales_flat_order_status_history AS comments ON comments.parent_id = sfo.order_id
```

Now this takes my original 6,000 records and turns it into 40,000 records.  The reason is that each order record can have multiple comment records.

What I need to do though is make sure only my original 6,000 order records are returned in my result.  I need to get all the comment records for each order from the `sales_flat_order_status_history` table and somehow concat them into 1 comments field on the result.

So if an order has 1 comment record or 6 comment records, it will combine the 6 into 1 and show it on the order record.

Is this possible with just SQL and can someone help modify what I have if it is?

---

**Working SQL from user LOCK's answer below...**

```
SELECT sfo.order_id, sfo.order_number, sfo.item_status, shipping.street, shipping.city, shipping.region, shipping.country_id, comment.created_at, comment.comment
FROM nam_order_items AS sfo
JOIN sales_flat_order_address AS shipping ON shipping.parent_id = sfo.order_id
AND shipping.address_type =  'shipping'
JOIN
(
  select
    parent_id
    group_concat(comment order by parent_id asc separator ' | ') as comment
  from
    sales_flat_order_status_history
  group by
    parent_id
) comment ON 
  comment.parent_id = sfo.order_id
```

Comment: Yes it is possible provided your comments don't exceed max length values for group_concat.  ... you could use [Group_Concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) `Group_Concat(comments.comment, ORDER BY CommentOrder ASC SEPARATOR ' ')` assuming you have a field for the order of the comments. named commentOrder (or adjust accordingly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:
`group_concat(comments order by id asc separator ' ') as comment`

Note that `order by id` should be the id of the comment (so the comments are correctly ordered when concatenated).
:

```
SELECT sfo.order_id, sfo.order_number, sfo.item_status, shipping.city, comments.comment
FROM nam_order_items AS sfo
JOIN sales_flat_order_address AS shipping ON shipping.parent_id = sfo.order_id
AND shipping.address_type =  'shipping'
JOIN
(
  select
    parent_id,
    group_concat(concat(created_at, ' - ', comment) order by entity_id asc separator ' ') as comment
  from
    sales_flat_order_status_history
  group by
    parent_id
) comments ON 
  comments.parent_id = sfo.order_id
```

Comment: Thank you!  Just a couple small changes and it works as I need it!  There is 1 addition I would like to make which maybe you can help as my attempt did not work.  I would like to add a `created_at` field from the comments and have it show right before each comment data.  I have added my fixed version of your SQL to the end of my question.  Can you possibly help in adding this new `created_at` field from the `sales_flat_order_status_history` table?

Comment: I tried to alter this line `group_concat(comment order by parent_id asc separator ' | ') as comment` by adding `created_at, ` into it like this `1group_concat(created_at, comment order by parent_id asc separator ' | ') as comment` with the hopes that it would get the created datetime field and insert into the comments but it gave this error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group_concat(created_at, comment order by parent_id asc separator ' | ') as comment from ' at line 9`

Comment: Do you want it as a separate row or part of the comment text? Is it a different value for every row in comments.comment?

Comment: it is a different value for each row in the comments and yes I would like to just have it be part of the generated comments text so it shows the date and time before each comment if possible.  SO far all my attempts are failing.  Thanks for your time and help